# React JS Unable to render image

Tags: reactjs

I've created a simple React app using `npx create-react-app react-portfolio`

1. Created simple page, all things are working properly on my local machine
2. Pushed to GitHub and published my portfolio into `gh-pages` (https://yanalinso.github.io/react-portfolio/) and it works!
3. I changed PCs, and cloned the same code from my repository (https://github.com/yanalinso/react-portfolio)
4. run `npm install` and `npm start` on my local machine, the images does not work anymore (logo and the background picture), but the CSS is working
5. https://ibb.co/4NchQJG (Result on my local machine)
6. https://ibb.co/RQVv6KB (Chrome console)
7. https://ibb.co/ZGN1cPd (File tree, same as with my other machine)
8. https://ibb.co/qmfwX44 (cmd run result)
9. My code is simple to use images

```
img src="img/logo1.png"
```

I can still push changes on GitHub page and it's working fine,
though images are not working on my local machine.

Comment: And what image are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, Im reffering to the logo image and page background

Comment: working fine for me though https://imgur.com/aVp7Ga8

Comment: hmm, I can't seem to make it work on my machine
1. git init
2. git clone https://github.com/yanalinso/react-portfolio
3. npm install
4. npm start 
5.cleared browser cache

Comment: not sure what it is but you are providing the github-pages which is up and running.
You should provide the page where the error happens

Comment: I'm not really sure how can i provide the error.
The code itself from the GitHub is exactly the same on my local machine,
I guess the problem itself is when running the website on my local machine

Comment: 1. You can change to another image, which will help refresh the cache (you know that you're loading a new image)
2. And if after uploading the new image, everything is working, then it is the issue in your local.
3. gh-pages requires the `homepage` attribute, which may not work in your local. By open the link of the src in a new window you will see where the image loads from (right click in src attribute -> open new tab)

Comment: I tried changing to other picture but still failed,

SOLUTION!

I've restored the package.json to default, so i've removed the config of gh-page on script and removed homepage == IT WORKS!!

Thanks guys for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import it first like this to tell webpack that JS file is using this image

```
import logo1 from './img/logo1.png';
```

and then this:

```
<img src={logo1} />
```

Comment: i've already tried that shows me this message
./src/HeaderPage.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './img/logo1.png' in 'C:\Users\Ayan\Documents\Mirai\React\Deployment\react-portfolio\src'

Comment: Put your image folder inside src folder. If you do this the path will be ''../img/logo1.png';' If you don't want to do this you can use this guide as how to refer to public folder https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: I see, If i cant figure this out, I will try your suggestion
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing to other picture but still failed,

SOLUTION!

> I've restored the package.json to default, so i've removed the config of gh-page on script and removed homepage == IT WORKS!!

Thanks guys for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching around regarding this and I find this very strange. I'm a beginner and the solution I can only come back with is

import ANYNAME from "path of file e.g ../images/logo1.png".

```
import ANYNAME from "../images/logo1.png"
```

Take note ../ is to reference a file outside the folder you are in.

If in the same folder use ./

Then when you are to use it

```
<img src={ANYNAME}/>
```

rather than `<img src="../images/logo1.png"/>` // This line doesn't work